# Saving variable to HDF5 in Scilab

Tags: hdf5, scilab

I am basically trying to create an HDF5 file to store a single matrix of 16 bit integers in a dataset with a specific path.
After reading the HDF5 Management section of the Scilab documentation I have tried the following:

```
file1 = h5open(‘/.../test.h5','a');
h5write(file1, '/example/data', variable, 'H5T_STD_I16LE');
```

In my understanding the first line should create the test.h5 file as I am using the 'a' parameter. The h5write according to the documentation should create the dataset if it does not exist, and write the supplied variable to it.

The file itself is indeed created however, the dataset is not created and the code returns the folowing error:

```
!--error 999 
h5write: Cannot create the dataset: /example/data
HDF5 description: component not found
```

Could someone please point out what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further experimentation with the h5 functions I have found a solution, and I thought I would answer my question as the answer is not stated clearly in the Scilab documentation.

In order to use h5write to create a dataset at e.g. /group/subgroup/dataset, the groups themselves have to be created first, as follows:

```
h5group(file, '/group');
h5group(file, '/group/subgroup')
```

One can then go on to create create the dataset at the path, as shown in the question.